# Check if file exists on Nginx using regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to translate some htaccess files to Nginx vhost configuration, and i'm having trouble with this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/img/id_$1_$2 -f
RewriteRule ^id/(.+)/(.+)$ img/id_$1_$2 [NC,L]
```

As you can see, this condition checks if a file exists using some regex to generate filename dynamically  by the URL entered.

The following nginx directive do the rewrite correctly but doesn't checks for the file bofore:

```
rewrite ^/id/(.+)/(.+)$ /img/id_$1_$2 break;
```

I just want to do this rewrite if the file really exists, and if not another rewrite will happen.

All ideas may help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @what_to_do;
```

From there, define a new location as follows:

```
location @what_to_do {
    rewrite ^/id/(.+)/(.+)$ /img/id_$1_$2 break;
}
```

The `try_files` directive will attempt to find files at $uri and then at $uri/ , where $uri is the path specified in the URL. Failing this, it will then go to the @what_to_do location block, where the rewrite is.

Bonus point: this also allows you to neatly separate your rewrite rules from the rest of the server config!

Comment: Got it worked for now! Thank you!
I'm trying to put this together with another conditions I have, when I got all working I'll edit this for thank you one more time.